# Friend function can manipulate object members?

Tags: c++

I am trying to set value for object member by using updateRollNo() function . But it's not working , Can i use friend function to manipulate object data ?
If i am using Student class member then it's working good but it's not working with friend function .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;

//Forward declaration
class Student ;
void updateRollNo(Student);
void checkRollNo(Student);

//Define class Student
class Student{
    private :
    int roll_no ;

    //Make friend function
    friend void updateRollNo(Student);
    friend void checkRollNo(Student);
};
int main(){

    Student s1 ;
    updateRollNo(s1);
    checkRollNo(s1);

    cout<<"\n\n";
    return 0;
}


//Define function updateRollNo()

void updateRollNo(Student stu){
    cout<<"\nEnter student Roll No : ";
    cin>>stu.roll_no ;
    cout<<endl ;
}


//Define function checkRollNo()

void checkRollNo(Student stu){
    cout<<"Roll No : "<<stu.roll_no ;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: *"But it's not working"* -- how is it not working? Did it overwrite your program with a copy of Minecraft? What symptoms can you describe that would give others a chance to realize they have the same problem as you (hence they can benefit from the answers).

Answer (score 0):

You problem is unrelated to the `friend` keyword (which is working fine); the problem is that you are passing your `Student` object by-value into `updateRollNo()`, which means that when the code inside `updateRollNo()` sets the `roll_no` member-variable, it is setting that member-variable on the local copy (`stu`) rather than on the `s1` object from `main()`.  That's why, when you subsequently try to print out the value inside `checkRollNo()`, you find that the value you print is still unset/uninitialized.

One simple way to get the behavior you want would be to modify `updateRollNo()` to pass the argument by-reference instead; that is, replace all instances of

```
void updateRollNo(Student);
```

with

```
void updateRollNo(Student &);
```

That way it will update `s1` directly rather than updating a temporary/local copy of `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void updateRollNo(Student);
```

By default, in C++ function parameters get passed ***by value***. This means that in the `updateRollNo` function its `Student` parameter is a ***duplicate copy*** of whatever was passed into this function. Any changes that `updateRollNo()` makes to this parameter will have absolutely no effect, whatsoever, on the original value that the caller passed to `updateRollNo()`.

In order for `updateRollNo` to modify whatever object gets passed to it, then either a pointer, such as

```
void updateRollNo(Student *);
```

or a reference, such as

```
void updateRollNo(Student &);
```

to the object must get passed in, instead of the object itself. A full discussion of pointers, references, and how to use them in C++ cannot be completely summarized in a couple of short paragraphs, so I'll refer you to your C++ textbook for more information.